# FadeInImage with unknown image at runtime

Tags: flutter

I have a FadeInImage in my app, with the image loaded in response to a user action. This means at runtime, I dont know the image, and just want the FadeInImage to not display anything.

If I pass in null for the image, or an empty string, I get a runtime error.

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
flutter: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///
```

Here it the relevant Widget declaration:

```
Container(
  height: 100,
  child:FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
  placeholder: kTransparentImage,
  image: _d2apiModel.emblemUrl,
  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
),
```

(where _d2apiModel is a Provider which is updated based on user actions).

I know I could put a default image in the asset bundle, copy it out of the bundle to the doc storage, get the file URI for the image, and use that as the default but 1) that seems like overkill, 2) i run into some async issues.

It seems like I am missing something obvious, but I cant figure out the approach. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show a regular Image with `kTransparentImage` while your provider hasn't been updated, and then show your `FadeInImage` when it updates:

```
Container(
  height: 100,
  child: hasProviderBeenUpdated
      ? Image.memory(
          kTransparentImage,
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
        )
      : FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
          placeholder: kTransparentImage,
          image: _d2apiModel.emblemUrl,
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
        ),
),
```

Comment: What is this **kTransparentImage** ?

Comment: Some image created by @mikechambers.

Comment: Oh okay @Hugo Passos Thank you